# Python: Variable not Defined, unsure how to carry variables over different defs

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am trying to use a variable from another function, but I'm not sure how to access it. I don't know where to put `global`, if that is even necessary.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#Defs
def getAngle1():
    angle1 = eval(input("Please enter the first angle: "))
    return angle1
def getAngle2():
    angle2 = eval(input("Please enter the second angle: "))
    return angle2
def getAngle3():
    angle3 = eval(input("Please enter the third angle: "))
    return angle3
def main():
    getAngle1()
    getAngle2()
    getAngle3()
    if angle1 == 90:
        print ("This is a right triangle!")
    elif angle2 == 90:
        print ("This is a right triangle!")
    elif angle3 == 90:
        print ("This is a right triangle!")
    else:
        print ("This is not a right triangle.")
#Driver
main()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/user1/My Documents/AZ_isitRightRevised.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/user1/My Documents/AZ_isitRightRevised.py", line 20, in main
    if angle1 == 90:
NameError: name 'angle1' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `getAngles` block of code stops executing after `return angle1`. Furthermore, by just calling `getAngles()`, you aren't storing the value(s) returned by this function anywhere.

First, let's rewrite `getAngles` as:

```
def getAngles():
    a1 = int(input("Please enter the first angle:"))
    a2 = int(input("Please enter the second angle:"))
    a3 = int(input("Please enter the third angle:"))
    return (a1, a2, a3)
```

Now, in `main`, you can do the following:

```
def main():
    angles = getAngles()
    # rest of your code
    # angles[0] is the first angle
    # angles[1] is the second angle
    # angles[2] is the third angle
```

Now, you have access to all three angles. What you could instead do is:

```
if 90 in angles:    # if it's a right triangle
    print("This is a right triangle!")
else:                  # otherwise...
    print("This is not a right triangle.")
```